# Auto Rerun of Oozie workflow when killed

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I have Oozie workflows not jobs that are being killed not failed due to unavoidable factors.
Instead of manually retriggering the workflow each time, is there any way to automatically retrigger it whenever the workflow is killed?